# CSS for Jquery plugin Chosen is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I know I have the correct path to the chosen.css:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/chosen.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But the dropdownlist does not look how it should (meaning like the standard select dropdownlist on http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/):

[image]

Then it just displays the options in bullet points.
Does anybody know what could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: A better way to check if a stylesheet is loaded is the networking tab of the console. Also, are we supposed to know how it's supposed to look?

Comment: Did you mean jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by using the Bootstrap + Chosen  CSS, rather than the normal chosen CSS.

Found here: http://alxlit.name/bootstrap-chosen/

I then just used the class chosen-select.

Comment: Sorry, can you put an example of your implementation? I have the same problem here.